# Reducing a second order differential equation into a first order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equations:

$$
\ddot{x} + \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0 
$$

$$
\ddot{y} + \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0 
$$

How do I go on to create 4 coupled first order differential equations for $x, y,\dot{x}, \dot{y}$?

Comment: the two new variables are $u = \dot{x}$ and $v = \dot{y}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fleshing out Will Jagy's comment on the question:

given that

$\ddot{x} + \dfrac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0, \tag 1$

$\ddot{y} + \dfrac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0, \tag 2$

we set

$\dot x = u, \tag 3$

and

$\dot y = v; \tag 4$

thus

$\ddot x = \dot u, \tag 5$

and

$\ddot y = \dot v; \tag 6$

then with some simple substitutions (1)-(4) become

$\dot u + \dfrac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0, \tag 7$

$\dot{v} + \dfrac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0, \tag 8$

$\dot x = u, \tag 9$

$\dot y = v. \tag{10}$

The system (5)-(8) is then a first-order sysem which is manifestly equivalent to (1)-(2).

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure that's what I was looking for, maybe I couldn't get your point. How do I get the first order differential equations for $x, y,\dot{x}, \dot{y}$?  Is what I am looking for already in your answer and I fail to see it?

Comment: Is your message incomplete? Thanks again :)

Comment: @rr_ed:  if you want the equation in terms of $x$, $y$, $\dot x$, $\dot y$, then you could write something like $(x')' = \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}$ and then the other $x$-equation would be $x' = x'$ and so forth.

Comment: @rr_ed:  my first message was accidentally posted before finished!  Sorry.

Comment: @rr_ed: i think you may be correct in saying what you are seeking is already in my answer.  I set $x'= u$ because it seemed more clear to me.  Does this help?  If not feel free to ask more.  Cheers!

Comment: It will make my day if you could provide one more step. I am unsure on where to plug x' = x'. So sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106855/discussion-between-rr-ed-and-robert-lewis).